# Get SSL certificate end date using Play WS

Tags: ssl, playframework, scalatest

I would like to write a test using Play WS and ScalaTest which checks if an SSL certificate is expiring soon.

I am able to print the certificate validation date by adding

```
ws.ssl.debug = [
  "record"
]
```

to my `application.conf`

However, I would like to access the result in a structured fashion in order to do assertions on it.

(I am aware this is possible using Java URL's `getServerCertificates` however, I wish to achieve this using Play WS if possible as that's what the rest of the project is using)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a part of Play WS to expose the peer certificates.  You need to look at the SSLSession and pull out the peer certificates.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLSession

In a pinch, you can do this by defining a custom hostname verifier in Play WS, which has access to the SSLSession.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#HostnameVerifier